# How to use a set of global and per subsite permissions in a multisite installation?

Tags: 8, configuration, multi-sites

**Use case:**
I have a multisite installation in which I want to define a global configuration to be available to all subsites. I define this configuration in the **default** site. For this example let's say that is:

- a role **editor**
- a content type **Article**
- a content type **Page**

Now..

1. In all subsites that role **editor** need to have the permission *"Use the toolbar"*. A global permission.
2. In **subsite-a**, I want to allow the editor to **only** add nodes of type **Article**
3. In **subsite-b**, I want to allow the editor to **only** add nodes of type **Page**

To add to that, let's say in the future I need to add a permission to the global set, I want to be able to import that set of permissions to all subsites without overriding any individual subsite permissions.

Currently I am using [config_split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) and added *user.role.editor.yml* to the conditional section but I can't seem to make it work with the scenario described above.

**Question:**
How to maintain a global set of permissions and per site set of permissions without the global config overriding the config of the subsite? They need to rather extend each other so to say.

Any suggestions/help?

Comment: Normally this would be a task for [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features). But it only works for all permissions I think, not for selected ones. You could try it out at least.

Comment: @leymannx thanks for the suggestion. Currently I am looking into the https://www.drupal.org/project/config_role_split module. I at least managed to get this working for modules but I think because of the tightly linked connection between roles and permissions this can't be done with config_split module alone.

Answer (score 1):

For now I solved this by creating a seperate **global** role which stays in the default shared config. I added the **editor** role to the conditional (graylist) section (configured per subsite) using config_split. So that way I am able to have seperate permissions for that role.

That global role can be automatically assigned to a subsite user during a new subsite install via a bash script/drush command for example.