# How can I sync just roles/permission config across multi-site instances?

Tags: users, configuration, multi-sites

On a Drupal 8 multi site, we need to have unified ROLES/permission config in all sites.

Then we'll assign these roles to users via interface or Drush.

How could I export / import? Or even better sync these via Drush or other means?

Comment: Have these roles and permissions in a Features module. Use one instance to export the Feature and import in all other instances, then export config in all instances.

Comment: But this would require all sites to have the same uuid for roles right? Any tip?

Comment: I don't think so. But you could simply sync the UUIDs, or sync the roles by putting them into the Feature as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a set of global and per subsite permissions in a multisite installation?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290077/how-to-use-a-set-of-global-and-per-subsite-permissions-in-a-multisite-installati)